# How do I find the Ur-Dragon?

Tags: dragons-dogma

As stated in the question, having difficulty finding it and there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer online.

So would like to know when/where and any pre-requisites that are required, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ur-Dragon is in fact what equates to the end game challenge of Dragon's Dogma. Once you have defeated the Great Red named Grigori and the Everfall has opened itself within the Capital city of Gran Soren, it is possible to fight the Ur-Dragon along with many other extremely powerful foes found within the Everfall.

The Everfall is essentially just that, a never ending tunnel into the heart of the world that loops into itself, allowing you to fall to the heart of the world and resume the fall from the sky far above the capital. Making landing upon one of the many terraces within the Everfall the only way to escape the never-ending loop.

Upon these terraces are portal's to another plane of existence, the same world, a different reality. In one of these other realities you will come upon the Ur-Dragon. The fight is hard. This specific fight has a 10 minute timer on it which is not shown but which will inevitably force the dragon to disengage and fly away after the time is up, thus requiring multiple attempts to fully destroy the dragon.

The Ur-Dragon does not regain health between encounters and is practically impossible to kill in 1 fight even in offline mode where his health never increases. In online mode, every time the Ur-Dragon is defeated, rewards are split between everyone that helped to defeat him, with better rewards being given to those who did at least a certain percent of the Ur-Dragon's life in damage, and even better rewards being awarded to the player who delivered the killing blow. Along with the rewards that players earn for killing the Ur-Dragon online, the next Ur-Dragon that spawns is stronger and has more health than the previously defeated Ur-Dragon.

Once you have completed the game and started a new game + with your original character, there is a much easier way to reach the Ur-Dragon via the solitary Riftstone located within the Starfall Bay(that little cove on the south side of the village) in Cassardis.